# Can I use the "IN" keyword in my spring data repository without using a @Query?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with mySQL and I have the API using spring data. Entities and Repositories are configured and working. I have a football matches table called "Matches" and each match has a `homeTeam` and an `awayTeam`.

I need to retrieve a list of all matches where "Team 1" and "Team 2" have played so I can build their "match history"

Here is my repository:

```
public interface MatchRepository extends JpaRepository<Match,Long> {

    List<Match> findByHomeTeamOrAwayTeam(
            @Param("homeTeam") Team homeTeam,
            @Param("awayTeam") Team awayTeam
    );
}
```

This works fine, it returns every match where "Team 1" was the homeTeam and "Team 2" was the awayTeam. I can also do findByHomeTeamAndAwayTeam and it returns the same list but filtered by the matches they both played.

Now the problem I can't get around is how can I use the "IN" keyword to fetch all matches that had "Team 1" and "Team 2" despite home or away situation.

For now I'm doing 2 calls to the same endpoint inverting the parameters but is there a way to represent the following???:

```
Select * from matches where homeTeam IN (1, 2) AND awayTeam IN (1, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use In

```
findByHomeTeamIdInAndAwayTeamIdIn(List<Long> homeTeams, List<Long> awayTeams);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: That seems like it will work if I'm able to pass a list as parameters. What is the syntax to pass a Collection or a List as a parameter in that JSON?

Comment: you mean that you want to pass a list of integers either? or how to oast the list itself ?

Comment: Yes so my problem is that team 1 and 2 are actually "http://localhost:4200/teams/1" and "http://localhost:4200/teams/31"

In order to request it right now, I'm doing a GET to: (For example) http://localhost:8080/matches/search/findByHomeTeamAndAwayTeam?homeTeam=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fteams%2F9&awayTeam=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fteams%2F36

Comment: Ahhh now it did work, Appearantly my (or yours) implementation was working, the problem was that it didn't get two urls as parameters. Now with the IDs, it is working great. Thanks a lot @Amr!!